# How do I add a button to this area of Outlook?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, office365, outlook-addin

So i have done some research and found how to add custom UI panels to various peices of the Outlook user interface via addons, however nothing I have looked at has answered this specific question.

I would like to add a new button to this area (blue arrow) along side these other buttons (pink arrow).  [image]

This menu appears both in the "People" context and  when you hover over someone's contact picture in outlook.

Also if anyone has a good documentation on the various pieces of the outlook UI and the proper names for all the different panes, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.